# Why do developer Orgs expire even if I've logged in just now?

Tags: developer-edition, environment-hub

I know that salesforce is expiring unused dev Orgs if nobody has logged in for a longer period.

I have received such emails like "Your Salesforce Developer Edition org is about to expire" - then logged in and all seemed fine.

Now looking in the environment hub, on some dev Orgs I see an expiration date. I'm 100% sure, that I have logged in recently, and to be super sure, I have logged in just NOW. Still, the expiration date stays. Only some random Orgs seem to be affected. I can't see any pattern in which org is affected and why. It feels like a BUG or an inconsistency to me.

Why do those Orgs have an expiration date? How can I get rid of it? How can this be preemptively prevented in the future?

[image]

Comment: +1 from me. If no one responds, try tweeting this to some official twitter accounts. You might be lucky to see some response as this looks like a bug to me!

Comment: @codeyinthecloud I have logged a ticket with the support. I hope that they will be able to help me with that. I have actually several cases open...

Comment: I know support can be really painful, Hope you find an answer, if you do please post here. Thanks